Proposed changes to Twilio-related tags
The Developer Advocacy Team at Twilio, who work with Stack Overflow on the Collective, have done an assessment of the Twilio-related tags on Stack Overflow and have proposed changes to several tags. There are three sections below, and we are requesting feedback on these proposed changes.
Community Managers will execute these changes, so there will be no work needed from the community.
Renames and merges
(the old tag will be a synonym to the new one)

authy renamed to twilio-authy (82 questions)

segment-io renamed to twilio-segment (68 questions)

twilio-programmable-chat renamed to twilio-messaging (399 questions)

twilioflexwebchat (10 questions) merged into twilio-flex (154 questions)

twilio-click-to-call (306 questions) merged into twilio-studio (210 questions)

twilio-conversations (132 questions) merged into twilio-api (2519 questions)


The rationale behind these tag updates is standardization and updating to current product naming and hierarchy.
Sendgrid tag merge
twilio-sendgrid will be a new tag, encompassing the following tags which would become synonyms:

sendgrid (3408 questions)

sendgrid-templates (164 questions)

sendgrid-api-v3 (501 questions)

sendgrid-api-v2 (30 questions)

sendgrid-ruby (21 questions)

sendgrid-rails (19 questions)


For the last two, we’d ensure that those questions are also tagged with ruby-on-rails
The rationale behind these tag updates is consolidation of unnecessarily specific or duplicative tags
Language-specific tags merges
Four language-specific tags used on questions about Twilio SDKs will be merged into the larger main tags for those languages.

twilio-php (724 questions) merged into php

twilio-node (47) merged into node.js

twilio-python (37) merged into python

twilio-javascript (31) merged into javascript


Rationale: Tags that are both language-specific and Twilio-specific are not particularly helpful for organizing questions related to the various SDKs. Ultimately the desired outcome is always an HTTP request, so when the question relates to usage of a specific language, it’s more appropriate to use only the language tag.

To those who are active in these tags: Do you have any concerns? Are there any reasons these changes should not be made?
Discussion will be open until Monday 23 September, at which point we’ll move forward with the renames/merges (unless there are reasons not to).

Not an expert and just my 2 cents, but having a twilio tag and a twilio-api tag, may be not needed. A merge of the two would be better. Another option would be to disambiguate and split up the twilio tag into it's correct sub-tags. (Not sure whether a whole catch-all tag, is useful)

Why would the new sendgrid tag be [tag:twilio-sendgrid]? There's no non-twilio sendgrid to confuse with, right? Seems unnecessarily specific.

Dear the Developer Advocacy Team at Twilio, a piece of feedback: it would've been better if one of you were posting these proposals here, rather than a member of Stack Exchange staff doing so after a behind-closed-doors conversation. Going through a middleman here doesn't provide any benefit at all to you, and is bad optics; you place yourself one step removed from the developer community that it's your job to dialogue with, and lose an easy chance to earn the goodwill of devs by demonstrating competence, conscientiousness, and concern for their needs.

twilio-php is the name of an SDK; at least in theory, you are adding information when you add [twilio-php] to a question already tagged [twilio] [php], since with [twilio-php] you know it involves the SDK but without it might be about interacting with Twilio via PHP without the SDK. I am nonetheless okay with nuking those tags (I doubt people reliably use them as I just suggested anyway!), but others might disagree. One important thing to do, not mentioned, is ensure all [twilio-php] questions are tagged [twilio] before merging into [php], and so on for the other languages!

@NickODell consistency?

@MarkAmery I'll step in here to be clear that it's Stack Overflow (and me specifically) that offered to make this post, similar to tag "cleanup" proposals I did for some of the other collectives. This starts with some consultation before bringing the proposals to the community. Personally, I see this as facilitating discussion rather than being a middleman, but I understand the perception. The Twilio team is happy to participate here and may do so after a few more days for answers and comments.

I don't see any updates on this. I assume you simply didn't get to this yet, right?

Two of the three proposed new twilio- prefixes in tag names are unhelpful
These all involve putting twilio- in front of product/service names that are inconsistently referred to with "Twilio" in their name, often because they come from companies Twilio acquired and then rebranded.
Specifically:

"Authy" is usually just called "Authy", not "Twilio Authy", even on its official, Twilio-controlled homepage, https://authy.com/. CTRL-F on that page reveals 8 matches for "Authy", zero of which are preceded by "Twilio". The only place the phrase "Twilio Authy" appears is the logo. Searching Stack Overflow for authy finds 403 results while "twilio authy" finds a mere 34.

The homepage of SendGrid, https://sendgrid.com/, likewise tends to refer to it as simply "SendGrid". (14 matches for "SendGrid" on the homepage, of which only 4 are preceded by "Twilio". Searching Stack Overflow for sendgrid finds 11 302 results, while "twilio sendgrid" finds a mere 155.

"Twilio Segment" is likewise usually referred to as just "Segment" on its website, https://segment.com/, but I figure this case is different to the previous two since the old "Segment.io" name is dead, so a change is needed here, and just segment is ambiguous. (Indeed segment is an existing tag that looks at a glance like it might be in need of burnination and blacklisting, since it does not seem to be used consistently at all.)


I suggest against including the twilio- prefix in the primary name of the first two of these tags. I actually have Authy on my phone (where the app name is simply "Authy", by the way, not "Twilio Authy"), and installed it prior to the (evidently half-hearted) rebranding to "Twilio Authy", but had no idea whatsoever prior to reading this post that it had been acquired by Twilio and rebranded. If I saw a question tagged twilio-authy, I would be misled and wrongly assume it must be about some Twilio-specific service I had never encountered.
Instead, I recommend the following:

Make a new twilio-authy tag that's a synonym of the existing authy tag (which would remain primary)
Make a new twilio-sendgrid tag that's a synonym of the existing sendgrid tag (which would remain primary)
... but do exactly as proposed for Segment, i.e. rename segment-io to twilio-segment, and make a new segment-io tag that's a synonym of it.


Given that those sites all seem to have "Twilio" in their logos, I'm not sure if it would be such a bad thing to name the tags consistently now, instead of leaving a few untouched whilst updating others.

I am not a user of any of these services, but I like the idea of everything looking the same :shrug

@M--SavetheDataDump The thing is, Authy and (as far as I know) Sendgrid aren't, like, part of Twilio (the service) or ancillary to it in any way; they're just standalone products/services which happen to have been acquired by Twilio (the company) and somewhat half-heartedly rebranded. It's like if Google changed the YouTube logo to say "Google YouTube" then proposed a tag rename here, except at least everyone knows YouTube is Google-owned and it's actually deeply integrated with Google, whereas I've had Authy for years (with very light use) without knowing it had any affiliation with Twilio.

That does make sense.

What are your plans for questions with twilio-language-specific tags that do not have twilio?

[twilio-php]-[twilio] (82 questions) (2 questions left)

[twilio-node]-[twilio] (3 questions) (resolved)

[twilio-python]-[twilio] (3 questions) (resolved)

[twilio-javascript]-[twilio] (4 questions) (resolved)



Update:
I took care of most of these. There are a couple of questions left to address which already had 5 tags and I was not sure if removing any of them is appropriate.
p.s. These tags need some curation. The quality of Q&A is not very promising.

I think the right answer here is obvious and is to add the [twilio] tag to these questions en masse before merging/deleting these tags - but yeah, I also noticed this wasn't part of the stated plan in Berthold's OP.

@MarkAmery I agree, obviously. Maybe I shouldn't have asked a rhetorical question :)

I would suggest that twilio-click-to-call be merged to twilio-programmable-voice (190 questions). Those questions all fall within the realm of voice calls, not necessarily Twilio Studio flows.
